# Load script from groovy script

Tags: groovy, load

File1.groovy

```
def method() {
   println "test"
}
```

---

File2.groovy

```
method()
```

I want to load/include the functions/methods from File1.groovy during runtime, equals to rubys/rake's load. They are in two different directories.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you don't mind the code in file2 being in a `with` block, you can do:

```
new GroovyShell().parse( new File( 'file1.groovy' ) ).with {
  method()
}
```

---

Another possible method would be to change `file1.groovy` to:

```
class File1 {
  def method() {
    println "test"
  }
}
```

And then in `file2.groovy` you can use `mixin` to add the methods from `file1`

```
def script = new GroovyScriptEngine( '.' ).with {
  loadScriptByName( 'file1.groovy' )
} 
this.metaClass.mixin script

method()
```

Comment: Another question, short one related. If i want to run a script as it was intended, script not class. Not invoking a method. Lika run or execute method.

Comment: You probably want [GroovyShell.evaluate](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html#evaluate(java.io.File))

Comment: @tim_yates I think you should change loadScriptByName( 'file1.groovy' ) to loadScriptByName( 'file1' )

Comment: @despot really?  I don't think it should be

Comment: Your solution got me on the right path but it isn't not quite right. You don't need to add a class inside the script your load.. I will give my answer.

Answer (score 22):

You can evaluate any expression or script in Groovy using the [GroovyShell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html).

File2.groovy

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
def script = shell.parse(new File('/path/file1.groovy'))
script.method()
```

Comment: Do you know if its possible to get the methods as in the current script. this += script. If you understand. This is more what I'm after.

Comment: calling method is wrong.  it should be script.invokeMethod("method", args)  assuming 'method' is static.

Comment: This is working nicely for me. `file1.groovy` neither needs to be an actual class nor have its methods being static.

Answer (score 15):

It will be easiest if `file1.groovy` is an actual class `class File1 {...}`.

Given that, another way to do it is to load the file into the `GroovyClassLoader`:

```
this.class.classLoader.parseClass("src/File1.groovy")

File1.method() 

File1.newInstance().anotherMethod()
```

Comment: you can also say def script = this.class.classLoader.parseClass("...");  def object = script.newInstance()

Comment: I've been using this also (in Jenkins) and it seems this is eating up PermSpace. See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169976/understanding-groovy-grails-classloader-leak
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712187/troubleshooting-grails-groovy-memory-leaks

Thus I wonder if this should really be recommended for server apps.

Comment: There is a quirk: so would be btter to consider a different way to call parseClass, and use the one with `.parseClass(new File(".."))` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993611/why-cant-i-instantiate-a-groovy-class-from-another-groovy-class

Answer (score 13):

**CAUTION**: This is a solution ONLY for Jenkins pipelines, as 'load' is only meaningful when running in a jenkins context. It is not part of the groovy language.

I am late on this but. This is how we have been achieving what you were asking. So, i have a file1.gsh like so:

**File1:**

```
println("this is a test script")

def Sometask(param1, param2, param3)
{
    retry(3){
        try{
            ///some code that uses the param
        }
        catch (error){
            println("Exception throw, will retry...")
            sleep 30
            errorHandler.call(error)
        }
    }
}

return this;
```

And in the other file, these functions can be accessed by instantiating first. So in file2.

**File2:**

```
def somename
somename = load 'path/to/file1.groovy'
 //the you can call the function in file1 as

somename.Sometask(param1, param2, param3)
```

Comment: Working perfectly on a Jenkins pipeline! (Note: At first, I had forgotten the `return this` at the end of my script, so `load` was returning `null`).

Comment: `load 'path/to/file'` works flawlessly, don't know why this was so hard to find, although if I remember correctly, it didn't work when prefixed with `./`

Comment: What 'this' returns? It should be like a Script object or sth in the groovy SDK. (I already checked the 'Script' object but no 'load' method in it.)

Comment: 'load' is only meaningful when running in a jenkins context. It is not part of the groovy language.

Comment: As @Hoobajoob mentioned above, this is a Jenkins pipeline DSL, not a Groovy language feature.

Comment: Doesn't work for JobDSL scripts, so it's a solution ONLY for Jenkins pipelines.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I'm using.

1: Write `any_path_to_the_script.groovy` as a class

2: In the calling script, use:

```
def myClass = this.class.classLoader.parseClass(new File("any_path_to_the_script.groovy"))
myClass.staticMethod()
```

It's working in the Jenkins Groovy script console. I have not tried non-static methods.

Comment: (same comment as to a similar answer above)
I've been using this also (in Jenkins) and it seems this is eating up PermSpace. See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169976/understanding-groovy-grails-classloader-leak
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712187/troubleshooting-grails-groovy-memory-leaks

Thus I wonder if this should really be recommended for server apps.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @tim_yates that uses `metaClass.mixin` should have worked without needing any changes to `file1.groovy` (i.e., `mixin` with the script object), but unfortunately there is a bug in `metaClass.mixin` that causes a SO error in this scenario (see [GROOVY-4214](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4214) on this specific issue). However, I worked around the bug using the below *selective* `mixin`:

```
def loadScript(def scriptFile) {
   def script = new GroovyShell().parse(new File(scriptFile))
   script.metaClass.methods.each {
       if (it.declaringClass.getTheClass() == script.class && ! it.name.contains('$') && it.name != 'main' && it.name != 'run') {
           this.metaClass."$it.name" = script.&"$it.name"
       }
   }
}

loadScript('File1.groovy')
method()
```

The above solution works with no changes being needed to `File1.groovy` or the callers in `File2.groovy` (except for the need to introduce a call to `loadScript` function).

Comment: This is great. It may be more accurate if renaming `loadScript` to `importScript`.