# Why can't I instantiate a Groovy class from another Groovy class?

Tags: class, groovy, classloader, instance

I have two classes.  One.groovy:

```
class One {

  One() {}

  def someMethod(String hey) {
    println(hey)
  }
}
```

And Two.groovy:

```
class Two {

  def one

  Two() {
    Class groovy = ((GroovyClassLoader) this.class.classLoader).parseClass("One.groovy")
    one = groovy.newInstance()
    one.someMethod("Yo!")
  }
}
```

I instantiate Two with something like this:

```
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
Class cl = gcl.parseClass(new File("Two.groovy"));
Object instance = cl.newInstance();
```

But now I get `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: script13561062248721121730020.someMethod() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Yo!]`

Any ideas?

Comment: `parseClass(String)` expects the text of the script/class as its parameter, not the file name.  Thus you're compiling a script containing a single statement which fetches the binding variable named `One` and then attempts to get the value of its `groovy` property.

Comment: I assume you know that you could say "def one=new One()" instead...?

Comment: @BillK Sure. I've used ``one`` as an instance variable in my local example, and it just stuck here.

Comment: I meant you don't have to use GroovyClassLoader at all, if you ar calling new One() from two and the .groovy file is in the classpath, it will just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it is occurring due to the groovy class loader method being called: the [string one](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html#parseClass%28java.lang.String%29) is to parse a script in text format. Using the `File` one worked here:

```
class Two {

  def one

  Two() {
    Class groovy = ((GroovyClassLoader) this.class.classLoader).parseClass("One.groovy")
    assert groovy.superclass == Script // whoops, not what we wanted

    Class groovy2 = ((GroovyClassLoader) this.class.classLoader).parseClass(new File("One.groovy"))
    one = groovy2.newInstance()
    assert one.class == One // now we are talking :-)


    one.someMethod("Yo!") // prints fine

  }
}
```