# How to load a groovy script from any location in a system in another groovy script

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am working with groovy and want to load a groovy script in another groovy script. Is there any way that i can load this script from any location in my system?

Can someone give an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including a groovy script in another groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136328/including-a-groovy-script-in-another-groovy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load script from groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004303/load-script-from-groovy-script)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Script.evaluate() function](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html#evaluate(java.io.File)) like:

```
evaluate(new File("test.groovy"))
```

Demo:

[image: Groovy evaluate function]

There is also [__groovy()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function available since [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31), you may find this useful as well.