# Jenkins use compiler warnings parser from script file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using Jenkins 2.46.3 and I want to ask if it is possible to move the parser script form the Mapping Script panel(Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Configure System->Compiler Warnings) into a file(ex. script.groovy) and import this script file in the Mapping Script panel?

I have multiple parsers that are for different files but some of them use the same script. That's why it is a hassle to edit the same thing over and over again so I was thinking of using one script file for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some experimenting the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004303/load-script-from-groovy-script)  did the job.