# Including some groovy scripts in a groovy script

Tags: groovy, include

I have some library scripts:
lib1.groovy:

```
def a(){
}
```

lib2.groovy:

```
def b(){
}
```

lib3.groovy:

```
def c(){
}
```

and want to use them in another scripts :
conf.groovy:

```
a()
b()
c()
```

conf.groovy is configured by user and he is not aware of my background lib scripts! he is only aware of provided methods/task : a(), b(), c(). actually i created lib scripts for user simplicity.

Is there any way to include all scripts in a lib directory (scripts lib1, lib2m ,lib3) into conf.groovy script(s)?
Or, is there any alternative mechanism to to that?
I am trying to run conf.groovy in a runner script/java class (using groovy shell, loader o script engine).

main.groovy:

```
File currentDir = new File(".")
String[] roots = {currentDir.getAbsolutePath()}
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(roots)
gse.run('confg.groovy', binding)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load script from groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004303/load-script-from-groovy-script)

Comment: Thanks  Szymon! but I do not want to insert def script = new GroovyScriptEngine( '.' ).with { loadScriptByName( 'lib1.groovy' ) } this.metaClass.mixin script in my conf.groovy file!. conf.groovy is a script which i am giving to user to config his tasks and i do not want user get involved with this. Actually I have another script(main.groovy) that runs confg.groovy (using GroovyShell, Loader or ScriptEngine). i edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: you have c() in lib2 and in lib3. Which one should be called ?

Comment: name corrected! it a() , b() and c()!

Answer (score 3):

**v1**

use `import static` and static methods declaration:

Lib1.groovy

```
static def f3(){
    println 'f3'
}
static def f4(){
    println 'f4'
}
```

Conf.groovy

```
import static Lib1.* /*Lib1 must be in classpath*/

f3()
f4()
```

---

**v2**

or another idea (but not sure you need this complexity): use `GroovyShell` to parse all lib scripts. from each lib script class get all non-standard declared methods, convert them into MethodClosure and pass them as binding into conf.groovy script. And a lot of questions here like: what to do if method declared in several Libs...

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure
def shell = new GroovyShell()
def binding=[:]
//cycle here through all lib scripts and add methods into binding
def script = shell.parse( new File("/11/tmp/bbb/Lib1.groovy") )
binding << script.getClass().getDeclaredMethods().findAll{!it.name.matches('^\\$.*|main|run$')}.collectEntries{[it.name,new MethodClosure(script,it.name)]}

//run conf script
def confScript = shell.parse( new File("/11/tmp/bbb/Conf.groovy") )
confScript.setBinding(new Binding(binding))
confScript.run()
```

Lib1.groovy

```
def f3(){
    println 'f3'
}
def f4(){
    println 'f4'
}
```

Conf.groovy

```
f3()
f4()
```