# Jenkins - load a groovy file into a DSL file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, dsl

I want to load a groovy file in a DSL file. If I process the DSL file I got following error message:

```
Processing DSL script folderA/job.dsl
ERROR: (job.dsl, line 2) No signature of method: job.load() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [./build.groovy ]
Possible solutions: find(), job(java.lang.String), find(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), run(), run()
```

The first two lines of my file **job.dsl**:

```
def workspace = '.'
def module = load "${workspace}/build.groovy "
```

I understand the error message in this way, there is no method load() in object job. The question is, how can I access global/build-in methods like load() in a DSL file?

Answer (score 0):

According to the message there is no `load()` method with a signature that contains a [`groovy.lang.GString`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html) parameter.

You could use:

- a [Double-quoted string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_double_quoted_string): `workspace + "/build.groovy"` or
- a [Single-quoted string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_single_quoted_string): `workspace + '/build.groovy'`

without interpolation which are interpreted as `java.lang.String`.

See also [Load script from groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9004303/1744774).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this doesn't help. :-( Now I get the following error message: ERROR: (job.dsl, line 2) No signature of method: job.load() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [./build.groovy]
Possible solutions: job(java.lang.String), find(), folder(java.lang.String), job(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure), wait()  -- This is nearly the same, but only the argument type is different.

Comment: @Andreas Where did you get the info that `load()` is the right method? It isn't mentioned a single time in the question & answers I linked to.